# Reflection order by property

Tags: c#, linq, reflection

I have a contract as following:

```
public interface IConsumer<in T>
{
    void Handle(T eventMessage);
    int Order { get; }
}
```

Then I have consumers that Implement this contact.

One of the consumer is:

```
public class TransferReceiverSmsConsumer : IConsumer<Event<Transfer>>
{ 
    public int Order => 1;

    public void Handle(Event<Transfer> eventMessage)
    { 
        var representation = $"{eventMessage.Entity.Sender} transferred {eventMessage.Entity.Amount} TL. to {eventMessage.Entity.Receiver} on {eventMessage.Entity.Now}.";
        Console.WriteLine("SMS:" + representation);
    }
}
```

Finally, I would like to find and create objects that implements this interface.

But I want to sort it by order, but the following dont work.

```
        var iconsumer = typeof(IConsumer<T>);
        var types = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().SelectMany(s => s.GetTypes())
                             .Where(p => iconsumer.IsAssignableFrom(p) && p.IsClass);

        var consumers = new List<IConsumer<T>>();

        foreach (var type in types.OrderBy(r => r.GetProperty("Order")))
        { 
            consumers.Add((IConsumer<T>) Activator.CreateInstance(type));
        }
```

How can I sort consumers by `Order`?

Thanks.

Comment: But you don't have an instance so `Order` does not have a value.

Comment: `OrderBy` works. What you try to do here though is sort *types* by the *PropertyInfo* object, not the contents of the `Order` property. What would make one property called `Order` to appear before another property called `Order`?

Comment: What are you trying to do with this code? If you don't have *instances* you can't check the values of properties. If you wanted to specify metadata on types and properties you should have used attributes.

Comment: Check the types in the [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations(v=vs.110).aspx) namespace. The attribute you want probably exists already, eg DisplayAttribute has an [Order](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayattribute.order%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) property

Comment: I am trying to order the consumers by their order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you only have the type (not an instance) there is no value to fetch for `Order`. I suggest you add a custom attribute to the implementing classes called Order and sort by that. (You can than remove it from the interface)

```
public class Order : Attribute
{
   public Order(int value)
   {
       Value = value
   }

   public int Value{ get; }
}


[Order(1)]
public MyClass<T> : IConsumer<T>
{
}

foreach (var type in types.OrderBy(r => 
            r.GetCustomAttributes(true).OfType<Order>().FirstOrDefault().Value))
{
}
```

Or you can sort the collection by `Order` after all the items has been created by the activator.

Comment: are you playing Dota2? I dont want to use Attribute. I want to use property.

Comment: You cant since you only have the type not an instance.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to use custom Attribute that placed for each class that implements your contract. And that custom attribute should have Order property. Otherwise you need to use reflection to get all final types that implement your interface and all instances of those types.